# How to draw inner stroke with Java2D

Tags: java, graphics, awt, java-2d

I just want to draw the circle which is exactly 15x15 pixels sized, and have fill and outline. I'm using Java2D. The problem is, as a result of sequentally called `Graphics2D.fill(circle)` and `Graphics2D.draw(circle)` the circle of 16x16 pixels drawn. It is because of internal Java2D outlinig mechanism, which for given 15x15 size provides 16x16 circle outline. Furthermore, if I ask Java2D to draw 14x14 pixels circle outline - it draws exactly 14x14 px. I have tried to play with antialiasing and stroke hints of renderer with no luck.
[image: illustration] Here are:

1. `RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE` and `Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 15, 15)` outline
2. `RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE` and same outline - notice 1px distortion
3. previous stroke hint and `Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 14, 14)`
4. `RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE`, `Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 15, 15)` outline and antialiasing hint

So, I can't draw 15px circle outline (also 13 px, 29 px and any odd size) with Java2D. Is there a way to draw some sort of inner stroke, which fills pixels at inner border of shape?

Comment: IMHO there is no way to do it in java Grapics/Graphics2D library because I was facing the same problem in the past and couldn't find any reasonable solution. Anyway, option 1 and 4 looks good in case you doesn't want to change your graphics library.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "1" is the option you want, but you've got an off-by-one error.  0,0 to 15,15 is actually supposed to be 16 pixels.  If you want 15 pixels, you'll need 0,0 to 14,14.

If it is specifically 15x15 with a predefined color, you can pre-render in a some image editing program and just use drawImage.

You can also consider translating by .5,.5. See what #2 looks like when you do Ellipse.Double(.5,.5,15.5,15.5)  You may be happier with that result.